# What did Weil consider the Euler characteristic when he formulated his conjectures?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In his famous paper (see here: http://berndt-schwerdtfeger.de/wp-content/uploads/pdf/nf.pdf) Weil conjectured that the zeta function of a variety $V/\mathbb{F}_q$ should satisfy a functional equation
$$Z_V(\frac{1}{q^nT})= \pm q^{n\frac{\chi}{2}}T^{\chi}Z_V(T)$$
where $\chi$ is the Euler characteristic.

Of course, it is not obvious how to define the Euler characteristic of such a variety in the absence of a cohomology theory. My understanding is that $\chi$ is properly defined using $\ell$-adic cohomology. However, in the same paper Weil wrote the following:

> $\chi$ [is] equal to the Euler-Poincaré characteristic of $V$ (intersection number of the diagonal with itself on the product $V\times V$).

What exactly is Weil talking about here? Also, does this definition of $\chi$ give the same Euler characteristic as the one defined through $\ell$-adic cohomology, or does it fail in ways Weil did not foresee?

Comment: I can't speak to exactly what Weil thought, but at least in differential geometry, you can calculate an intersection number of two oriented submanifolds with complementary dimensions by homotoping them to a transverse intersection, assigning a sign to the points of intersection by using the orientation, and summing over the intersection points.  This can be done cohomologically by taking the cup product of their fundamental classes.  In algebraic geometry, I think this is accomplished using the Chow ring, but I don't know how much of that was developed by Weil's time.

Comment: Right. My understanding of the situation in differential geometry is that you take the Poincaré duals of the homology classes of the submanifolds, take the cup product of these cohomology classes, then apply Poincaré duality again and (hopefully? always?) it represents some (0-dimensional) submanifold whose oriented points you can count. But you still need a homology/cohomology theory satisfying Poincaré duality to make sense of this, no?

Comment: Plus, I like to visualize varieties over a finite field as just some points floating in the air, so I don't know how far you can take the transverse intersection idea in algebraic geometry. (Maybe you can?) I also don't know anything about the Chow ring.